# I want to read width of div and img only after it has a correctly loaded value

Tags: jquery

I want to display some images as thumbnails within a div. I only wanted to display enough images to fit the width. When I started doing this I noticed the width that I read kept changing each time I ran it. So I implemented the code below to try and read the width only once the element is loaded. I wrote this code based on other stack overflow questions and a whole bunch of Google searches but the console messages do not print which means it is not entering the load function. I am stuck and any help would be great. Note that I have not done much of work on jquery and this might be completely wrong. Thanks in advance for your time.

```
<body>
        <div id ="visibleThumbnails", class="visibleThumbs"></div>
            <!-- Below is all the images that will be used. The images below are hidded -->
        <% @cover_file.each do |image_file| %> 
        <%= image_tag("#{image_file}", class: 'imgThumbnail') %>
        <% end %>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            //slides is the list of hidden images from above
        slides = $('#Thumbnails').find('.imgThumbnail');
        var div_width = 0;
            // The code below is what actually fills the div with the appropriate number of images
        while (div_width == 0) {
            $('#visibleThumbnails').one('load',function()
            {
                div_width = $('#visibleThumbnails').width();
                            //I can never get this log to get printed
                console.log("DIV width "+div_Width);
                img_idx = 0;
                var img_width = 0;
                while ((img_width < div_width) && (img_idx < slides.length)) {
                    slides.eq(img_idx).one('load',function(){
                        img_width= img_width + slides.eq(img_idx).width()

                        if (img_width < div_width){
                            $('#visibleThumbnails').append(slides.eq(img_idx).clone().fadeTo('fast',1));
                        }
                        img_idx = img_idx+1;
                    });
                    if (slides.eq(img_idx).complete){
                        slides.eq(img_idx).trigger('load');
                    }
                }
            });
            if ($('#visibleThumbnails').complete){
                $('#visibleThumbnails').trigger('load');
            }   
        }
    })
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: why not get the maximum dimensions of the div and then use fixed dimensions for your imgs so that you can calculate how many will fit ahead of time?

Comment: You have a lot going on in your code and it is somewhat difficult to understand what exactly is working for you versus what is not working... do you think perhaps you could make a jsfiddle to help illustrate the problem?

Comment: I removed the part of the code that is not relevant.  I have added a couple of comments. The thing is the console.log that I have in the code does not ever get printed. Also I am using this code rather than a fixed number of images to make sure that it displays OK on any form factor. I will try to put this up on jsfiddle later